# How should sonarqube quality gates be used with automated builds?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

Our organization is currently using sonarqube to fail a SCM triggered automated builds.   Right now, our quality gate is firing when there are any open or reopened issues (with the understanding that someone needs to fix or "accept" the issue before the build will continue).  Unfortunately, there are concerns that we are delaying code propagation for code formatting issues and other very minor offenses.  Also, this is requiring quite a bit more manual intervention than we originally expected.

We want certain classes of issues to trigger a build failure, but the "new  issues" filter only fire once.  on the subsequent automated build they are no longer new so they no longer fire the gate.

Is there anyway to set up the equivalent to "Break the build if there are more than 0 open/reopened breaking/critical issues."?

EDIT:  Sorry, I forgot to mention that we have about 15k "confirmed" issues that is serving as our backlog. so the non-new issue filters wont work either.  Also I am open to minor changes to our workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, the following configuration should do the job:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that we have about 15k "confirmed" issues that is serving as our backlog.  So this wont work.

Comment: OK, so you won't be able to achieve what you want (Break the build if there are more than 0 open/reopened breaking/critical issues."). What I'd suggest you to do would be to check that there's no new critical nor blocker issues since last analysis, and that there's also no reopened issue since last analysis (whatever the severity).

Comment: Are quality gate options extendable with a plugin?  If so, we might be interested in perusing that option.

Comment: No, this is not possible.